# Left Outer Join a Data frame with a Series object by key on data frame, index on series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Is it possible to join a series object to a dataframe without having to turn the series into a dataframe?

Currently, I calculate something, get a series as a result, and have to turn the series into a dataframe to merge the two:

```
clicked_series = p.clicked.sum();
temp_df = pd.DataFrame({'ad_id':clicked_series.index, 'clicks':clicked_series.values})
full_df = pd.merge(full_df, temp_df, on='ad_id', how='left')
```

Is it possible to conduct a left outer join on the series and dataframe directly, without having to create a temporary data frame?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `reindex`

```
full_df['clicks'] = clicked_series.reindex(full_df.ad_id).values
```

---

***old answers***

Use `join`
technically, I'm still converting to a `pd.DataFrame` but...

```
clicked_series = p.clicked.sum();
full_df = full_df.join(clicked_series.to_frame('clicks'), on='ad_id', how='left')
```

Another option is to use `pd.concat`.  But this will look like an outer join.

```
pd.concat([full_df.set_index('ad_id'),
           clicked_series.rename('clicks')], axis=1).reset_index()
```

Comment: That's as much as I have found as well. The first still converts the series into a data frame, and the second doesn't allow for a left outer join.

Comment: You're a wizard. Thank you.